# Android Spinner has a bigger height when an option is selected

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

In my layout I have 6 spinners that are not necessaritly displayed. 
When no option is selected, the height is good, but when an option is selected, it looks bigger and I didn't find anything about that online.

Here is the spinners without an option selected

[image: Without option selected]

And when an option is selected

[image: Spinner with option selected]

Here is the Layout which contains the spinners:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutDetail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/details">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtDetail1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/medium_text"/>

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinDetail1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/spinner"/>

            </LinearLayout>
            ... Same thing 5 more times ...
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is my java code for the spinners:

```
private void initializeDetails() {
    List<Detail> details = mainAct.details;
    detailSpinners = new Spinner[details.size()];

    int marginTop = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 16, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    int marginEnd = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    int marginStart = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 8, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;

    for (int i = 0; i < details.size(); i++) {
        int tvID = getResources().getIdentifier("txtDetail" + (i + 1), "id", mainAct.getPackageName());
        int spinID = getResources().getIdentifier("spinDetail" + (i + 1), "id", mainAct.getPackageName());

        TextView txtDetail = inputView.findViewById(tvID);
        Spinner spinDetail = inputView.findViewById(spinID);

        txtDetail.setText(details.get(i).getTitle());
        List<String> answers = details.get(i).getAnswers();
        answers.add("");
        final int answersSize = answers.size() - 1;

        ArrayAdapter<String> detailAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mainAct, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, answers) {
            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return answersSize;
            }
        };

        spinDetail.setAdapter(detailAdapter);
        spinDetail.setSelection(answersSize);

        params.setMargins(marginStart, marginTop, marginEnd, 0);
        spinDetail.setLayoutParams(params);
        params.setMargins(0, marginTop, marginEnd, 0);
        txtDetail.setLayoutParams(params);

        detailSpinners[i] = spinDetail;
    }
}
```

I can't put a `wrap_content` height for the spinners because if I do they aren't visible. 
I don't think that the xml is the problem because I used a lot of spinners with the same code and I never had this issue. The difference is that I edit the `LayoutParams` programmatically and there's probably something I'm doing wrong.
I just want the spinners to keep the same height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `padding` to 0 on the spinner xml element.

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinDetail1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/spinner"/>
```

**Update:**

The wrapping LinearLayout has a height of `"wrap_content"` while the Spinner has a height of `"match_parent"`, assuming this will act the same as wrap_content as it is only constrained by the LinearLayout.

Setting a specified height in pixels to the `Spinner` should resolve this.

```
android:layout_height="60dp"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I just tried and it didn't change anything.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: I didn't want to set a fixed height but it works so I'll use that, ty